# .NET 3.5 ActiveX dll InteropServices.COMException

Tags: .net-3.5, interop, activex

Using vs2008 .NET 3.5 SP1

I am trying to use an ActiveX dll in my c# console application project and I am getting this runtime exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800702E4): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {4E58088E-7275-4EAA-8958-A9CCC971DDE9} failed due to the following error: 800702e4.
```

How do I go about finding out a solution to this issue?

I have used regasm.exe to register to DLL previously and it registered successfully.

name of DLL is `interop.sterling.dll`

simple code:

```
using SterlingLib;

  public class OrderPlacer
    {
    private void SendOrder()
        {
            var order = new SterlingLib.STIOrder();
        }
}
```

I added the reference to this DLL by browsing to it and adding it as a reference - then placing in the `/bin/debug` folder

using reflection:

```
SterlingLib.STIOrderClass is a class whose base class is System.__ComObject
     It implements the following interfaces
         SterlingLib.ISTIOrder
         SterlingLib.STIOrder

SterlingLib.STIOrder is an interface
```

I am running Vista so I think this may be a UAC issue not allowing full rights unlike it would if I was running XP.

Comment: Could you add some details about the component that you are using, and possibly also add the code that causes the error?

Comment: regasm.exe is to register .net assemblies as com, did you mean you used regsvr32?

Comment: I tried regsvr32 and it returned back with message module was loaded but entry point DLLRegisterServer was not found. Make sure that the dll is a valid DLL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

0x800702e4 suggests that the process must be run with elevated privileges.

Comment: Here's a list: http://blogs.msdn.com/joshpoley/pages/errors-007-facility-win32.aspx